# Twitter-like UIScrollView with ViewControllers as pages

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiscrollview

[Video of the issue!](https://vid.me/QHcN)

Example of what I mean by Twitter-like UIScrollView:

[image: Twitter Image]

I basically have it working, but I have this small glaring issue and I don't know where it is coming from. I have checked all the constraints and values for my two view controllers, but something is off.

In short,

The code that creates the NavBar and then populates it with the two ViewControllers side by side:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var navBar: UINavigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.width, 64))

    navBar.barTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    navBar.translucent = false

    //Creating some shorthand for these values
    var wBounds = self.view.bounds.width
    var hBounds = self.view.bounds.height

    // This houses all of the UIViews / content
    scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    scrollView.frame = self.view.frame
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    scrollView.delegate = self
    scrollView.bounces = false
    self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.bounds.size.width * 2, height: hBounds)

    //Putting a subview in the navigationbar to hold the titles and page dots
    navbarView = UIView()

    //Paging control is added to a subview in the uinavigationcontroller
    pageControl = UIPageControl()
    pageControl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 35, width: 0, height: 0)
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 0.3)
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    pageControl.numberOfPages = 2
    pageControl.currentPage = 0
    self.navbarView.addSubview(pageControl)


    //Titles for the nav controller (also added to a subview in the uinavigationcontroller)
    //Setting size for the titles. FYI changing width will break the paging fades/movement
    navTitleLabel1 = UILabel()
    navTitleLabel1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 8, width: wBounds, height: 20)
    navTitleLabel1.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    navTitleLabel1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    navTitleLabel1.text = "Title 1"
    self.navbarView.addSubview(navTitleLabel1)

    navTitleLabel2 = UILabel()
    navTitleLabel2.alpha = 0.0
    navTitleLabel2.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 8, width: wBounds, height: 20)
    navTitleLabel2.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    navTitleLabel2.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    navTitleLabel2.text = "Title 2"
    self.navbarView.addSubview(navTitleLabel2)

    //Views for the scrolling view
    //This is where the content of your views goes (or you can subclass these and add them to ScrollView)

    feedViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FeedController") as FeedViewController

    view1 = feedViewController.view

    addChildViewController(feedViewController)
    feedViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    view1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, wBounds, hBounds)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(view1)
    self.scrollView.bringSubviewToFront(view1)

    //Notice the x position increases per number of views

    secondViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondController") as SecondViewController

    view2 = secondViewController.view

    addChildViewController(secondViewController)
    secondViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    view2.frame = CGRectMake(wBounds, 0, wBounds, hBounds)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(view2)
    self.scrollView.bringSubviewToFront(view2)

    navBar.addSubview(navbarView)
    self.view.addSubview(navBar)
}
```

I've looked at my storyboard and both ViewControllers seem identical in regards to their constraints.

I know this is an issue because both ViewControllers are populated by  UITableViews. When I scroll through the SecondViewController, it works perfectly. When I scroll through the FeedViewController, there is a small white space at the top that I can't seem to get rid of and it shows that the text cuts off there. I've been stuck on this for a long time and if there is any other information needed, I'll gladly provide it.

**Edit: Included video of the issue. If I could, I would bounty this question right now. I don't understand the cause**

**Update: After swapping both ViewController positions, I have noticed that the problem does not lie with either ViewController. The problem lies with page 1 being set lower. When swapped, the original SecondViewController also experienced the same behavior**

Comment: Maybe I just don't fully understand how subviews get added to views.

Comment: I suppose I could always make the constraints on the left one move up by 20, but I don't think I should have to do that. Which is the puzzling part about all this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think everyone who implements this runs into this issue at some point. The issue isn't with the first ViewController. Simply adjust the constraint to be 44 from the top. The issue is with the second ViewController and it isn't so much an issue when you understand how they work. Technically, it is off to the side and hence its top constraint does not adhere to the Navigation Bar, so what you have is a constraint - 20. Which, depending on how you originally placed your constraints, can give you this seeming issue.

But basically, anyone and everyone will run into this issue when implementing this.

**TL;DR: To make everything seamless, your second, third, fourth, fifth, etc. page View Controllers need a constraint + 20 of your first View Controller. With my set-up, I use a constraint of 44 for my first View Controller and hence 64 for the second**